# Перемещение объекта в место тача(тапа) Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется область, на которой установлены элементы Mask. На этой области у нас объект, который должен перемещаться в место, куда был произведен клик(тап, тач).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настроить перемещение от одного объекта к другому мне удалось. Но вот при использовании закомментированной строки объект улетает в бесконечность. И более того, данный метод не выдает нужных координат. Он снимает координаты только с видимой области поля, на котором находится объект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С использованием Ray что-то ничего не выходит, объект вовсе перестает реагировать.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

P.S: Андроид, не PC. Тачи нужны...

Answer (score 1):

Код не проверял.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
    }
}
```

А какие рамки задавать уже решешь задачу сам.

И не кидай, пожалуста, кода в скриншотах. Это запрещено.

Comment: Здравствуйте. При использовании подобного кода объект улетает в угол экрана и по Z принимает отрицательное значение, ввиду чего его не видно. Также пропадает эффект какого-либо движения, он просто перемещает объект: https://imgur.com/RxXEdQG

Comment: вопрос: а что за обьект это вообще? Это спрайт на канвасе? Или что-то другое?

Comment: Здравствуйте. "Pole" и "Obj" - это Image. Game Object - соответственно своему названию.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что MousePos имеет не мировые координаты, соответственно нужен:

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPosition(MousePos), Time.time / ariiveTime);
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. При использовании данного кода(только Point вместо Position) объект улетает в угол экрана и по Z принимает отрицательное значение, ввиду чего его не видно. Также пропадает эффект какого-либо движения, он просто перемещает объект: https://imgur.com/RxXEdQG

Comment: Ну видимо у вас используется какая то другая камера, а не та что в `Camera.main` прописана. Сделайте в скрипте ссылку на камеру через которую смотрите и уже для нее делайте расчет положения объекта